# C# webservice needs to convert SOAP to REST on the fly

Tags: c#, xml, rest, soap

I am trying to write a translation layer for a test system for which I am writing software. I am using LabVIEW for the test system and that uses a RESTful webservice. I have implemented the REST Methods and they are working OK. The remote Test controller and data service layer etc are written in C# and SQL and these are the items I have to interface with using SOAP. I have a simple webservice client that has been written in C# for the SOAP side by a colleague. I basically need to take the the objects collected by the C# program and then build a small XML that can be sent to the REST URI as post data.

I have done an introduction to C# course but it was a "this is C# based on your text based language" not helpfully when I mainly code in LabVIEW. I have trained with C and a bit of C++ ages ago but really struggled in the course it was a very steep learning curve and not used C# since the course about 3 months ago. I want to learn C# and thought this would be an easy way to start but I am struggling so far.

OK some code:

```
[WebMethod]
[SoapHeader("RMSSvcHeader", Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.InOut)]
public ReturnStatus Initialise(string uri)
{
    ReturnStatus rs = new ReturnStatus();
    try
    {
        rs.Message = HttpPostXml(uri, @"C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\RMS\XMLMessages\Initialise.xml");
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        rs.Status = 1;
        rs.Message = exc.Message;
    }
    return rs;
}
```

So this current version uses a method to post a set XML file of dummy data to the REST URI as POSTDATA for test purposes.
The SOAP data passed to this method exposes a UUID (GUID) and the Method name. This means that from this I have enough info to create the XML for the POSDATA message that need to be sent to the REST service.
Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Initialise>
    <UUID>d7051980-a690-11dd-ad8b-0800200c9a66</UUID>
</Initialise>
```

I just need pointing in the right direction as how best to convert the objects to XML for the REST service.

Thanks,

Neil.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using WCF instead? [There is an easier way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529.aspx) to publish those services for REST interaction.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is have webservices, pages that expose the service in a RESTful way, or a SOAP way (through spitting back the XML).